# keywords in NEGATIVE Sentiment using sentiment Analysis(stanfordNLP)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

My requirement is to read the input text and undergo sentiment Analysis. If the sentiment analysis is NEGATIVE i should get only the negative keywords used in the context.

The following is the code snippet to achieve the sentiment analysis:

String tweet="the movie is worst";
Properties props = new Properties();
    //   props.put("pos.model", "D:\Stanford_API's\english-left3words-distsim.tagger");
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos,lemma,parse, sentiment");

```
     pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        int mainSentiment = 0;
        if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
            int longest = 0;

            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);
            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) 
            {
                Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);

               SimpleMatrix sd= RNNCoreAnnotations.getNodeVector(tree);

               System.out.println("---sentiment----"+sd.negative().eig());
               //System.out.println("---sd.get(0)----"+sd.get(0));

                String partText = sentence.toString();
                if (partText.length() > longest) 
                {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }

           }
        }
```

Pls suggest how i can get the keywords from the sentence if the sentiment analysis is NEGATIVE ?

Comment: You want stanford-nlp specific answer? I guess it uses RNN for sentiment classification. I doubt if there's a straight forward way to get the negative words. Think if your sentence is "The movie is not at all good" and it classifies this as negative but you dont have a negative word. If you are okay, maybe you can give it a try by simple BOW classification and just checking out the 3 highest most weighted words for each sentence and see how that looks. I know it's basic thing but it might work depending on your use case.

Comment: Post examples of what kind of KEYWORDS you want...

Comment: The input will be a paragraph which will have complete information about the problems.                                                                              **Ex:** many times i called the customer care but nobody has given complete information about the solution.                                                                                                            **Issue category:** call center